# Restoring themes and icons to default state?

Tags: unity, themes, icons, gtk

I tried to install various `themes` on Ubuntu 14.04.1 on two computer though I succeed on one I completely messed up on the other. The problem is although I have deleted the theme files and `ppa-purged` the corresponding repositories and after `purging` the themes, I still have left-over files and tweak tools(Gnome TT, UTT) still show some of the deleted themes and tries to switch to them when clicked on. Is there a way to restore everything to the default state at the time of installation? I think deleting folders/files inside `/usr/share/icons`, `~/.icons`, `/usr/share/themes` and `/.themes` are not enough as evidenced by the presence of the names of the themes in the dropdown list of the tweak tools. How can I achieve my aim?

Comment: Restore your system back-up... If you do not have one, read: [What's a good back-up strategy for one PC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)  You're user type 4...

Comment: (but that comment is for the future...)  On to your current problem...  ;-)  Does this also happen in the guest session?  (And please *do* read the article from the previous comment, and *do* vote it up if you think I'm right.)

Comment: Actually I somehow figured it out that due to my lack of rest those days I was unable to notice some files lurking around in the aforementioned directories being the culprit in this scenario. Anyways thanks for your help and I will ready the article

Comment: Also, don't forget to answer your own question and dropping me a note @Fabby.  If it's a good answer I'll upvote it!

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, I answered my own question as you can check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was apparently caused by leftover files in the `/usr/share/themes` directory. I knew that the files causing the entries in the **Ubuntu Tweak Tool** and other tweak tools should reside in either `/usr/share/themes` or `~/.themes` since I deleted the latter one I found out that the files causing the problem was in the `/usr/share/themes` directory, I deleted them then purged all the PPAs associated with the themes then I got a near fresh install although I am not exactly sure if I had deleted any default themes by then or not. Anyways, the moral is that directly copy pasting themes from another computer may not work, especially if they are installed via PPA and you mess with permissions by carrying it with an USB pen formatted in **NTFS** or something that does not support Linux permissions.